# Can the P-Gate be written in terms of pauli matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin

The P-Gate is an operation which maps $a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$ to $a|0\rangle+be^{-i\phi}|1\rangle$ by means of a phase shift and can be written as \begin{pmatrix}1& 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\phi}\end{pmatrix}
My question is whether it would be possible to write it in terms of Pauli matrices.

Similarly, can a phase shift for 2 qubits such as \begin{pmatrix}1& 0 & 0& 0\\ 0 & e^{-i\phi_1}& 0& 0 \\ 0 & 0& e^{-i\phi_2}& 0\\ 0& 0& 0& e^{-i\phi_3}\end{pmatrix} be written in terms of Pauli matrices or in terms of the generator of $SU(4)$. I am not seeing any combination which achieves either.

Comment: any matrix can be linearly decomposed in terms of (possibly tensor products of) Pauli matrices. See e.g. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8725/55

Comment: But since the z-pauli matrix is a special case of the p-gate it should not be possible no?

Comment: what do you mean precisely with "can be written with"?

Comment: Could it be expressed as a product of pauli matrices in exponential form?